# Cannot install PyAutoGUI - receiving error

Tags: python, pyautogui

Can anyone help me on this? When I try to install PyAutoGUI, I am getting the following error:

```
C:\Python 34>pip.exe install pyautogui
Collecting pyautogui
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03BB69B0>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pyautogui/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03BB6B70>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pyautogui/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03BB6C30>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pyautogui/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03BB6CF0>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pyautogui/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03BB6DB0>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pyautogui/
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03BB6E50>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pyautogui/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03BD3130>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pyautogui/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03BD31F0>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pyautogui/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03BD32B0>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pyautogui/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03BD3370>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pyautogui/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyautogui (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pyautogui
```

Much appreciated. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Download the package from here [PyPI.PyAutoGUI](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a3/69/c8b0cab7cbc6badbc0079392e5d4b50f3e4be63e0091f0f414bd1ea4ac07/PyAutoGUI-0.9.50.tar.gz). Browse to the folder where the file has been downloaded and open Command Prompt over there.
Type the command : `pip install "PyAutoGUI-0.9.50.tar.gz"` (Check the file name in case it changes with future releases of mentioned package.)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a problem with PyAutoGUI, but rather this is pip's behavior when it can't connect to the internet properly. Check your network, firewalls, proxies, and so on.